# Combining P-Values from multiple trials of the same experiment

Tags: probability, statistical-significance, p-value, causality, granger-causality

this is my first question here, a little background about me, im a biomedical engineer, im studying a PhD in Neuroscience, and a Micromaster in Statistics and Data Science.

Here in my lab, very few people are interested at maths , models, etc. (incredible i know...) So i have so little references to ask about the best math procedure to validate or model things. Once said my sad situation lol this is my question:

Im doing a Causality test based on Granger Causality between 3 zones in the brain.

The analysis give me p - values associated with statistical causal conections between signals.

as an example of a event of interest:

`ZONE          P Val
1 -> 2       .056345 
1 -> 3       .005321
2 -> 1       .003214
2 -> 3       .000123
3 -> 1       .245021
3 -> 2       .002455`

So imagine i have 50 events of interest and i apply this analysis for each one, then i will have 50 p-values per conection, and i want to give as a result the "mean" granger causal connection per pair of zones, as a function of the statistical significance, in other words by the p-values: ¿What is the better way to combine all those p-values?

I can use the Fisher method? or apply the mean of the p-values over the trials, or there are more appropiate methods?

Thanks

Thanks a lot since now.

Comment: We can only talk sensibly about combining p-values in relation to some specific question of interest. What are you trying to find out?

Comment: Hello Glen_b , each p-value represent how statistically strong is the evidence to think about the signal recorded at zone 1 Granger Causes the signal in zone 2 and so on.

Comment: So I have 6 p-values per trial , I'm doing this analysis just before an event of interest, and I have 50 events of interest, so at the end, I will have 50 p-values per connection, but I can't give as a result 50 graphs , so I want to combine those 50 p-values per connection, to talk about what connections and in which direction resulted with strong statistical evidence over the 50 trials.

Comment: I think you'll need to provide more detail in order for people to give helpful answers. Zones? Connections? Events? Please make it more clear what data you collected, and what questions you are trying to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look into the bonferroni correction. Basically the more tests you conduct it increases your chances of a type I error. Rather than taking the mean of the p-values you would divide your alpha by number of tests.

"For example, if a trial is testing m=20 hypotheses with a desired alpha = 0.05, then the Bonferroni correction would test each individual hypothesis at 0.05/20 = 0.0025."

Then you would compare each path's p-value against the newly established alpha threshold.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction

Comment: HI, in this case if i set mi alpha to 0.05 and i have 50 trials, the new boundary should be .05/50 ?

Comment: How you would combine in first place the  p - values ? by Fisher's method ? or something else?

Comment: What kind of analysis are you running? A regression? Are you sure that you want all separate models per connection? Or is it appropriate to group z so that you would have one model to analyze multiple connections between zones? I have never encountered combining p-values in my field, usually if you have a bunch of models you either talk about them separately and adjust the alpha boundary using the Bonferroni correction or think of a way to combine the variables into fewer models.

Comment: Oh I just read about the causality test. I think you should either group the connections into a single model, e.g. zones 1 2 and 3 predicting 4. However, this would give you the coefficient per zone predicting 4 while controlling for the other connections so it changes the model a bit. Unless that is what you want to do.

Comment: It's a pairwise Granger Causality Test based on Granger Causality Toolbox (Seth,2005)

Comment: If I were you I would think about whether I want to compare connections between zones within the same model or if I want to strictly examine connections between only two zones at a time (like you provided in the output). If its the latter case then I think its only appropriate to talk about each connection separately and adjust the alpha with the bonferroni correction. I think you can also avoid overly conservative alpha adjustment by only dividing the alpha by number of models with the same outcome, so in your output .05/2 since each zone has two models where the zone is the outcome.

Comment: This is how I was trained in public health, you could also look at others in your field who has used these kinds of models with similar analysis and see how they adjust their p-values or if they include multiple zones predicting a connection on a single zone etc.